# jQuery Datatables plugin not saving state cookies?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've got a site using the jQuery Datatables plugin, which is mostly working very well.

However, for some reason its state saving code isn't being fired. Other options set at initialisation are being correctly picked up, but for some reason the state saving code isn't; there's no evidence of effect, cookie etc set, using either the straight initialisation parameter or specifically defining fnStateSave and fnStateLoad parameters (copying the code from the example at http://datatables.net/blog/localStorage_for_state_saving). It's all otherwise completely standard, data starting in the DOM, for the purposes of testing no other parameter set.

Is there a non-obvious setting I should make or limitation I should know about?

Comment: Can you please post your code? are you using the latest version of datatables 1.9.4?

Comment: Yes, I am - I'll try and get some code up over the weekend for a demo, this code isn't on a public site.

Comment: I recommend using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make this work you need *DataTables* 1.8 or higher...

`bStateSave: true`

> Enable or disable state saving. When enabled a cookie will be used to save table display information such as pagination information, display length, filtering and sorting. As such when the end user reloads the page the display display will match what thy had previously set up.

Taken from [DataTables Documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/features#bStateSave)

A full working example can be found [here](http://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/advanced_init/localstorage.html) *(debugging this example in Chrome showed both the `fnStateSave` and `fnStateLoad` being called.)*

**which does the following:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            var data = localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
            return JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
});
```

***Only using the following scripts:***

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I'd tried going through that example and comparing it to my code but for some reason it's not working; I'll have another look and see what I can find.

Comment: @eftpotrm not a problem if you can get a jsFiddle going with just a javascript [][] then I can find the issue for you much quicker.  Note that this code won't work if you are using it from File:// location and not a website hosted via IIS/Apache/ETC

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Worked well for me.